# Pick Up Wheelchair Passenger at SFO airport

Tags: united-airlines, sfo, accessibility

I need to pick up a 94-year-old passenger at San Francisco International Airport.  She requested wheelchair assistance when she booked the flight.

Where do I go to pick her up?  Is there a special place?

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing where you would find the special assistance desk for the airline, say "I'm here to pick up ___ ____ who is arriving on flight __ and has requested wheelchair assistance. Where can I meet her?", and have them help you.

Comment: I've seen this done, but not at SFO. As far as i know the procedure is for airport/airline staff to conduct the passenger to the normal arrivals area. I would imagine other arrangements can be made, but I think that's the default procedure.

Answer (score 3):

SFO has multiple terminals with separate secure areas.  Since there are multiple exits, they have signed "meeting points" for different gates.  The staff assisting will deliver the passenger to that point at least (although most that I've worked with will assist and take the passenger to baggage arrival as well if requested).

I did this about 12 months ago.  I met the passenger at the meeting point, and then the three of us went to baggage where the passenger released the wheelchair.

The airline website has a page showing the meeting points [here](http://www.flysfo.com/to-from/meeting-passengers)
[image]

Image from www.flysfo.com